# Finding distance of a building from road junction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

I have a peculiar problem which i cannot think of way to solve.

I need to find distance of a building from the nearest road junction. This would include distance to the nearest road and how far is that point of road from nearest junction.

I tried 'Near' but it gives either distance to road or distance to junction (displacement).

See image for example.

[image: Problem Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each road is line connecting 2 intersections, the only challenge here is finding near Point location (chainage) on the road.

1. convert result of near analysis (NEAR_X, NEAR_Y) between houses and
   roads into points.
2. Use Linear referencing or [solution here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166878/distance-between-points-along-polyline-arcgis-for-desktop/166888#166888) to assign chainage to these points
3. Calculate distance to nearest intersection along road as min(chainage, road_length-chainage)
4. Spatial join (closest) between houses and roads will give you a distance to road